# Programmatically create users + generate temporary password email

Tags: developer-console

Where in the Developer Console can you find the check box "Generate new password and notify user immedietley"

I need to find it so i can make sure i incorporate it into my program so the user can atleast log in. Everything else is done! this is the last piece of the puzzle!

Comment: You won't find it in the developer console

Comment: Ok, So if i need this to be called when i create a new user in my external program. How would i go about doing so? Or should i just log in to salesforce manually and reset or generate a password?

Comment: I've personally only ever accessed the new user email generation so they can create their own password through the Setup. Obviously, one can create users via Apex, but I've never attempted to create the emails, etc. Its the user that creates their password from the log-in email. You might check the SF object reference for guidance. You can also create users via REST. The REST api might be another place to look.